# how to Add data to store through redux-forms in react?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, react-redux-form

I have created a friendlist app which displays the data and performs certain operations like add and edit delete i want to create a add page which adds the details to the list..how can i push the data and display it in the table?
and i want to use redux-forms for add page.

here is the complete project code-

reducers/index.js-

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import Friends from './static'
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form'


const rootReducer=combineReducers({
  friends:Friends,
  form:formReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

reducers/static.js

```
export default function(){
  return [{
    key: 1,
    name: 'Steve',
    phone: '8974645875',
    email: 'steva@gmail.com',
    work: 'Doctor',
    city: 'newyork',
  }, {
    key: 2,
    name: 'Smith',
    phone: '9424645875',
    email: 'smith@gmail.com',
    work: 'Architect',
    city: 'newyork',
  }, {
    key: 3,
    name: 'Bella',
    phone: '9546855875',
    email: 'bel@outlook.com',
    work: 'Engg',
    city: 'newyork',
  }, {
    key: 4,
    name: 'Rk',
    phone: '7544645875',
    email: 'rk@gmail.com',
    work: 'Engg',
    city: 'newyork',
  }];
}
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {friendlist} from '../actions/index'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import showResults from '../showResults';

class FriendList extends Component {
  render(){
    console.log('ADD',this.props.friends.friends)
   let filteredFriends=this.props.friends.friends.filter(
     (friend)=>{     
      return   Object.values(friend).indexOf(this.state.search)!==-1;     
   }
   );
   let newdat=this.props.location.newdata;
   let id,name,phone,email,work,city;
   if(newdat){
          id=Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
          name=this.props.location.newdata.name;
          phone=this.props.location.newdata.phone;
          email=this.props.location.newdata.email;
          work=this.props.location.newdata.work;
          city=this.props.location.newdata.city;
          filteredFriends=filteredFriends.concat({name,phone,email,work,city});
          console.log('FILTEREDDATA',filteredFriends)

     let newArray = this.props.friends.friends.slice();
     newArray.push({id,name,phone,email,work,city});
    this.setState(this.props.friends.friends);

   }

   console.log("STATE",this.state,'LIST',filteredFriends,'NEW Array')

    let rows=filteredFriends.map(friend => {

      return   <tr>
          <td>
            { friend.name }
          </td>
          <td>
            { friend.phone }
          </td>
          <td>
            { friend.email }
          </td>
          <td>
            { friend.work }
          </td>
          <td>
            { friend.city }
          </td>
          <td><input type="checkbox"/>Important</td>
          <td><button><Link to={{pathname: '/edit',  state: { key: friend.key,phone:friend.phone,name:friend.name,email:friend.email,work:friend.work,city:friend.city }}}>
      Edit</Link></button></td>
        </tr>

    })
    return <div>
    <div className="header"><h1>Friendlist</h1><hr/></div>

    <center><br/>
    <div >
    <table>
        <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Phone number</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Work</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Mark as Important</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
      <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
    </center>
</div>
}
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    friends:state
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return bindActionCreators({friendlist:friendlist},dispatch);
  }

const List = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(FriendList)

export default List
```

add.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import showResults from './showResults';
import AddFriend from './AddFriend';
import {createStore} from 'redux'
import reducers from './reducers'

export default class AddNew extends Component{
  render() {
    return (
    <div style={{ padding: 150 }}>
      <AddFriend/>
    </div>
  )}
  }
```

AddFriend.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

const AddFriend = props => {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = props;
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <label>Name</label>
        <div>
          <Field
            name="name"
            component="input"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Name"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Phone</label>
        <div>
          <Field
            name="phone"
            component="input"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Phone"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Email</label>
        <div>
          <Field
            name="email"
            component="input"
            type="email"
            placeholder="Email"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Work</label>
        <div>
          <Field
            name="work"
            component="input"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Work"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="employed">City</label>
        <div>
          <Field
            name="city"
            component="input"
            type="text"
            placeholder="City"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        <button type="button" onClick={reset}>
          Clear Values
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'newfriend', // a unique identifier for this form
  fields: ['name', 'phone','email','work','city'],
})(AddFriend);
```

Can anyone please help me to do this. where after adding the data gets added in the list that is friendlist and the added data is listed in the table.

Comment: what you need to do is update the FriendList Redux store when you submit the redux form, for that firstly you should have an onSubmit event on the form

Answer (score 0):

Pass an `onSubmit` handler to the Redux Form like

**Redux form calling component**

```
import {addFriendAction} from './path/to/action'
...
handleSubmit = (values) => {
    var data = {
        name: values.name,
        email: values.email,
        phone: values.phone,
        work: values.work,
        city: values.city
    }
    this.props.addFriendAction(data)
}
...
<FriendForm onSumit={this.handleSubmit} />
...

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({addFriendAction}, dispatch)
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent);
```

Change your FriendForm to have an onsubmit and make use of Field from reduxForm

```
const FriendForm=({addFriend,fields:{name,phone,email,work,city},handleSubmit})=>(
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <center>
    <div>
      <label>First Name</label>
      <Field type="text" component="input" placeholder="Name" name="name"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Last Name</label>
      <Field type="text" component="input" placeholder="Phone" name="phone" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Email</label>
      <Field type="text" component="input" placeholder="Email" name="email"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Work</label>
      <Field type="text" component="input" placeholder="Work" name="work"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>City </label>
      <Field type="text" component="input" placeholder="City" name="city"/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </center>
  </form>
)


export default reduxForm({
  form: 'friend', // a unique name for this form
  fields: ['name', 'phone', 'email','work','city']
})(FriendForm);
```

You action will look like

```
export function addFriendAction(data) {
    return {type: 'ADD_FRIEND', payload: data}
}
```

and then update the reducers

```
const FriendListReducer = (state = initialState, action ) => {
     switch(action.type) {
          case 'ADD_FRIEND': 
                return {...state, friends: action.payload}
          ...
          default: return state

     }
}
```

Comment: Glad to have helped :) @SmithSteve

Comment: import it from Redux form first before using. Also this is not a tested working code, but a way to do it. You will have to make the appropriate changes according to your design

Comment: i have uploaded the complete code could you help me to make the add page.

Comment: As i am new to redux i am not able to do it.i am sorry if i am asking silly questions.

Comment: Could you help me with this? @Shubham Khatri

Comment: I am a little busy today, however I think I have added all the details to get this thing working